# Alternate to $.each that only executes for first?

Tags: jquery

In my code; I wish to remove $.each, rather to only execute the code once for the first instead of each of the objects; how do I do this?
This code executes 10 times; I wish to only execute it once for the first asset

```
            $.each(assets,function(a,b){
                var asset=b;
                console.log(asset["assetName"]);
                var link = "http://meepcity.com/item.php?id="+asset["assetId"];
                $.get(link, function(data) { 
                    console.log("data loaded");
                });
                //console.log("Name: "+asset["assetName"]+"\nID: "+asset["assetId"]+"\nIsLimited: "+asset["assetLimited"]+"\nBG Color: "+asset["assetBG"]+"\nRFS: "+asset["assetRFS"]+"\nCoin Price: "+asset["assetCoinPrice"]+"\nToken Price: "+asset["assetTokenPrice"]);
            });
```

Comment: So, `var asset = assets[0]`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any reason you can't remove the statement like:

```
var asset=assets[0];
console.log(asset["assetName"]);
var link = "http://meepcity.com/item.php?id="+asset["assetId"];
$.get(link, function(data) { 
  console.log("data loaded");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `$.first()` to reduce your set:

```
$(assets).first()
```

... and then use it as if it were only one element.